# How to access WCF soap service in iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, wcf, soap, ios7

i am developing iphone and android app that capable of accessing soap web service. in android i become much easier with ksoap2 third party library. but when i comes to iphone i dont have any library or inbuilt methods for that.

I surfed in web i got the link http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/39819-how-to-call-wcf-service.html. i tried the same procedure but i got status code 400 (The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.).

the request format

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
<Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IService1/Logindetails
</Action>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
<Logindetails xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
 <value>       {"SessionId":"dfg45fsg","IpAddress":"192.168.0.1","UserName":"tiru123","Password":"ku204","MacAddress":"192:158:012:45","IMEINo":"testno","Location":"Adyar"}</value>
</Logindetails>
</s:Body>
 </s:Envelope>
```

response format

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
            <ActivityId CorrelationId="57d29115-decc-4d40-8716-2495ee9d9c20" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">a5d15743-7290-41fd-a7e6-47f8a1dc23d6</ActivityId>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
            <LogindetailsResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
                <LogindetailsResult>{"CollectorId":0,"IMEINo":null,"IpAddress":null,"IsChangePassword":false,"IsRefund":false,"Location":null,"MacAddress":null,"MerchantGroup":"Direct","MerchantId":264,"Password":null,"Roles":null,"SessionId":null,"UserId":450,"UserName":"tirupoomi123","Usergroup":"Merchant"}
            </LogindetailsResult>
            </LogindetailsResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

my iphone code

```
NSString *soapMessage =  @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"
"<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
"<s:Header>\n"
"<Action s:mustUnderstand=\"1\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none\">\n"
"http://tempuri.org/IService1/Logindetails\n"
"   </Action>\n"
"   </s:Header> \n"
"<s:Body>\n"
"   <Logindetails xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
"    <value>\n"
"{\"SessionId\":\"dfg45fsg\",\"IpAddress\":\"192.168.0.1\",\"UserName\":\"tiru123\",\"Password\":\"ku204\",\"MacAddress\":\"192:158:012:45\",\"IMEINo\":\"testno\",\"Location\":\"Adyar\"}\n"
"</value>\n"
"   </Logindetails> \n"
"</s:Body> \n"
"</s:Envelope>";

NSLog(soapMessage);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.189/Service1.svc?wsdl"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];
[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/IService1/Logindetails" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Soapaction"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

if(theConnection) {
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
}
```

if anyone have any solution please help me

This above code works fine in normal wsdl web service. But not in wcf service.

I think that the problem with web service.

If any body have sample wcf sevice with iphone access please share with me

Comment: You can follow a few links. Here are these

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982622/consume-wcf-web-service-using-objective-c-on-iphone

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417808/wcf-or-web-services-asmx-for-ios-application

Comment: might be there is some mistake in to you request please check your sope service using this method then try to implement  [http://soapclient.com/soapmsg.html](http://soapclient.com/soapmsg.html)

Comment: The above method works on wsdl service not in wcf service