# Any benefit in using ServiceStack over ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, servicestack

I'm planning a web API which will be used by browsers/JavaScript and Android App (open to other potential clients too).
While I read there are many benefits in using ServiceStack vs WCF, I'm not sure if it is still better option now that we have ASP.NET WebAPI.
I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699083/servicestack-vs-asp-net-web-api/9709236#9709236) where ServiceStack author compares it to WCF but says that "WebApi is different to WCF in that it encourages REST-ful API design."

So, is ServiceStack still a better option over ASP.NET WebAPI, and why?

Also, how ServiceStack fits into OWIN/Katana story?

Comment: Opinions on web fx's vary wildly, there'll never be a consistent answer on which is best/better - take time to evaluate both and see what you're most comfortable with. [ServiceStack's homepage](http://www.servicestack.net) gives a good overview of what's in ServiceStack and some of its advantages. Note: OWIN support is undecided, [Raise a feature request](http://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests) listing end-user benefits you'd want in OWIN support, also next v4 of [ServiceStack is Commercial/AGPL+FOSSEx](https://plus.google.com/106787359118990653189/posts/g8TcZaE7bv9).

Comment: This is a highly subjective and controversial subject and probably will be closed. You better move it to programming stackexchange.

Comment: I wasn't actually aiming at subjective opinions, but wanted help to understand if there is a real benefit in using it over ASP.NET WebAPI. However, how do I move question to programmers.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699083/servicestack-vs-asp-net-web-api

Comment: @Ved I did see that, but I felt the same as [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699083/servicestack-vs-asp-net-web-api#comment22053222_9709236)

Comment: @Aliostad-Sadly, there are over-zealous users @ programmers.stackexchange.com that would also close this type of question or vote it down because it "can not be answered".  This kind of question/group evaluation is very useful and I wish that the SE community would try harder to support it.